# Kafka stream consumer skipping a few offset no log compaction enabled

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

kafka server version: `3.2.0`
kstreams version : `2.7.2`

I have a producer, which is producing to topic `foo`, I can see the offset from the producer in the logs.
We have kafka stream application reading from the same topic `foo`. What I am observing is that the consumer skips reading offset. Sometime the skip is over 30 to 40 offsets. I am printing the offset in `process` method using `ProcessorContext`.offset() method.
Skipping of offset seems to be very common, will using `ProcessorContext`.offset() result in every offset being printed ?.

Some points

1. No kafka rebalance has occurred.
2. No restarts of the container
3. We have 3 state store defined in the streams application, and the change log topic has replication factor of 1.
4. We have kafka broker outage where few broker were down some extend period of time, about 3 weeks back. I dont know how things impact the message i should consumer today.
5. We have NOT set processing.guarantee, so default should be AT_LEAST_ONCE. We do not have transactions enabled, so it cant be transactional messages. which are skipped

The log to print offset if the first line in the `process` method.

Question:

1. What internal kafka stream logs can I see to see if messages are consumed.
2. Any reason why the messages could be skipped

Comment: Why not run kafka-streams 3.2.x version? Are you **sure** you are not using transactions in your producer, they are enabled by default in Kafka 3.x. What are you using to produce? Is it skipping transaction marker offsets?

Comment: we are using 2.7.2 version of kafka-client.
I see `transactional.id` set to null in the producer config.
I see `processing.guarantee = at_least_once` . 
Based on this is i concluded that transaction is not enabled.

Comment: But your Kafka server version is 3.2, so maybe it would help if you used the same (or higher) client version... Clients aren't meant to be behind the server since the network protocol can change.

Comment: `Are you sure you are not using transactions in your producer, they are enabled by default in Kafka 3.x` -- that's not correct. "Idempotent producer" is enabled by default -- that's a config -- if you use transactions, you have to write code to use the corresponding transaction API calls on the producer...

Comment: I am confused: `What I am observing is that the consumer skips reading offset.` -- vs `will using ProcessorContext.offset() result in every offset being printed ?.` -- Both sentences seems to contradict each other. What you mean by that you "observer consumer skips reading offset" ?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax will using ProcessorContext.offset() result in every offset being printed ?. was a question, i wanted to find out that if offset printed inside the process method print every offset, which i assume it would

Comment: Yes, it should print every offset -- you might want to print `partition()`, too, if you have more than one partition to reason about it.

Comment: thank you, looks like it does print offset, I was missing a few offsets for other reasons related to my code.